# Update Multiple Row CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to update my database but when i click save button and redirect to index. it doesn't change anything.
Here is my Controller :

```
public function update_agenda() {
                for($i = 1; $i < count($this->input->post('did')); $i++) {
                    if($this->input->post('did')[$i]!= '' ){
                        $data = array (
                    'nama' => $this->input->post('dnama'),
                    'keterangan' => $this->input->post('dketer') );
                $id= $this->input->post('did');
                $this->load->model('agenda_model');

                    $where= array('id'=> $id);
            $res = $this->agenda_model->UpdateData('agenda',$data,$where);
            if($res >=1){
            redirect ('ajaxsample/index');
            }
}
```

Model

```
public function UpdateData($tabelName,$data,$where){
        $res =$this->db->update_batch($tabelName,$data,$where);
```

and this is my View. I don't know why when i click button save. It doesn't work.
Please help me, thanks :D

```
<?php foreach ($daftar_agenda as $agenda) { ?> <tr> 

        <td> <input type ="checkbox" id="haha" onclick="#" class=checkbox1 name="checklist" value=<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>> <?php echo $agenda->id; ?> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="hide" name="did" value="<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>"> </td>

        <td> <input type="text" name="dnama" id="nama_" class="yes" value="<?php echo $agenda->nama; ?>" disabled /> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="dketer" id="ket_" value="<?php echo $agenda->keterangan; ?>" disabled> </td>
```

Save

Comment: How can this match an ID... $id= $this->input->post('did'); above you are refering to it as an array

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1: In your view file, you have an input, named 'did'. It is not an array, so in your Controller you cannot refer to this as an array.
[And it's better to use the "id" tag once, or it has to be unique (but it's a problem for javascript functions, in this case it is not important)]

Problem #2: In your Model function, the return parameter is missing.
And it will be better like this:

```
public function UpdateData($tabelName, $data, $where){
  $res = $this->db->where($where)
        ->update($tabelName, $data);

  return $this->db->affected_rows(); // returns the affected rows number, so it needs to be higher than 0, if any row was affected.
}
```

Problem #3: In your Controller function, it is enough to load the model once, at the top of the function. And you redirected the page after the first $i of the for method. So you need to place the redirect() outside the for method.

Your Controller function should be fine with this solution:

```
public function update_agenda()
{
    $this->load->model('agenda_model');
    $done = 0;

    for($i = 1; $i < count($this->input->post('did')); $i++)
    {
        if($this->input->post('did')[$i] != '' )
        {
            $data = array(
                'nama' => $this->input->post('dnama'),
                'keterangan' => $this->input->post('dketer')
            );

            $id = $this->input->post('did')[$i];
            $where = array('id'=> $id);

            $res = $this->agenda_model->UpdateData('agenda', $data, $where);
            $done += $res;

        }
    }

    if($done >= 1)
    {
        redirect ('ajaxsample/index');
    }
}
```

But for this solution, your 'did' input needs to be an array!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data=array();     

          if($this->input->post('did')!= '' ){
                     $data[] = array (
                        'nama' => $this->input->post('dnama'),
                        'keterangan' => $this->input->post('dketer'),
                         'id'=>$this->input->post('did'),
                     );

          }

      $this->load->model('agenda_model');
      $res = $this->agenda_model->UpdateData('agenda',$data);
      if($res >=1){
          redirect ('ajaxsample/index');
      }
```

In Model

```
public function UpdateData($tabelName,$data){
        $res =$this->db->update_batch($tabelName,$data);
}
```

Comment: still get error like this :  Undefined variable: data

Comment: add this before foreach $data=array();

Comment: echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
add this before below line,to check whether you are getting $data or not
  $res = $this->agenda_model->UpdateData('agenda',$data);

Comment: before add echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die; . i can't click my save button. and now i can click the button. but still don't change database. and when i go to ajaxsample/update_agenda the result is :Array ( )